# Create view to compile information from multiple lists

Tags: list, web-part, view

I have been following this guide:

[How to Link Two Lists and Create a Combined View in SharePoint 2013](http://ignatiuz.com/blog/how-to-link-two-lists-and-create-a-combined-view-in-sharepoint-2013/)

to combine the information from 5 lists into one view, but after adding the columns, at the 'Sort and group' option there are no columns? what am i missing? is there maybe an easier way to combine information from all of the lists?

Comment: You say you're trying to combine 5 lists.... So you have the same data in 5 different lists so you just want them to merge together one list after the other, or you have 5 lists that are related to each other?

Comment: There is a requirement, from a management perspective to have an overview off all of the lists in one view. As a work around, i have created one list now with views to break it down into each of the 5 sections. Only down side to this is i cant permission control the views.

Comment: I don't exactly have enough information but... 
If the data is being created/edited by a group of people that can see everything and you only need to create "view/read" permissions for a subset of the data then you might be able to solve your problem by creating 5 folders, have the creators put the items into the proper folder and then create item level permissions on the folder.

Comment: Another option if you simply can use security by obscurity, that is you don't put any obvious link to the entire list anywhere, and create pages (wiki or web part) and then put a view on the page, removing the link to the source list.  Then change the permissions for that page...

Comment: The best answer probably would have been to create a custom client side web part that uses SOAP Services or REST endpoints to pull the data from all 5 lists and displays them... but... you'd have to be able to develop the code.